# Using promises in Angular's ngResource

Tags: angularjs, promise, ngresource

I'm trying to send a receive a response from a server using ngResource module of Angular. I'm using promises but it doesn't work, I think there might be something wrong with my code. It goes as it is :

Controller:

```
var LoginController = angular.module('LoginController', [

]);

LoginController.controller("LoginController", ['$scope','$location','LoginService',  function($scope, $location, LoginService) {


    $scope.user = {}


    $scope.checkCredentials = function () {
        var userCredentials = LoginService.get();
        userCredentials.$promise.then(function(result){
            $scope.user.login = response.login;
            $scope.user.password = response.password;
        });


    };
}]);
```

Rest module:

```
var RestServices = angular.module('RestServices', ['ngResource']);

RestServices.factory('LoginService', ['$resource','$routeParams',
    function($resource, $routeParams){

        return $resource('/user',{},{
            get: {method:'GET', isArray:false}
        });
    }]);
```

If I put the line:

```
var userCredentials = LoginService.get();
```

directly inside declaration of controller, it works and object user is filled properly and send to my view, but when I try to do that in a function invoked by clicking a button (like it is in my code) it doesn't fill user object properly. What might be wrong with my code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you put the other code snippet please?

Comment: .then*function(result) but pulling data from response?

Comment: add a .catch block to your LoginService.get() invocation to see if something fails

Comment: are you using two way binding syntax in you view for the user object?

Comment: Yes, two way binding is working properly (tested using static values for variables I'm using)

Answer (score 0):

Change "result" to "response"!

```
var userCredentials = LoginService.get();
userCredentials.$promise.then(function(response){
    $scope.user.login = response.login;
    $scope.user.password = response.password;
    });
```

But you can also achieve the same in a more succinct and idiomatic way:

```
LoginService.get(function(data){
    $scope.user.login = data.login;
    $scope.user.password = data.password;
    });
```